# How to avoid a page in an iframe "bouncing" when pull down from the top?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, drag

I have a iframe that display a webpage (eg. apple.com) in my HTML5 page on the touch device like this

```
<div>
    <iframe class="full_screen" src="http://www.apple.com" />
</div>
```

So when you use your finger to pull the page down, there will be a chunk of space displayed on top of the screen when you reach the top of the page. (like the "pull down to update" feature on some iphone app).

Is there any way to disable this "pull_down_to_update-like" feature in my HTML5 page?

Thanks in advance.